# Multiple Angular datatables on same page error showing pagination controls

Tags: angular, datatables, angular7

I have 3 Angular Datatables in the same html,  the user can decide the tables that he wants to populate... Datatables are placed on a class row div so they are on the same Y axis in the page...

the point is when the 
rightmost table is empty or the user doesnt want to list it; the other rendered datatables loss the pagination controls

any ideas of how to resolve this issue? thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show your piece of code which you have tried so far and not just the description.

Comment: Sorry for being late, the issue was caused because dtOptions where messed up, solved the issue l time ago, thanks for the atention and have a nice day

Comment: Ok @juan not a problem :) have a nice day